# Why does fastlane build to testflight keep failing on archive?

Tags: xcode, react-native, fastlane

I haven't changed my fastlane config at all from times it was working. But now after sometime when I needed to do another build it fails now on this part. What should I do here?

This is the following I'm getting.

```
[15:42:40]: ▸     Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'app' from project 'app')
[15:42:40]: ▸     Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'app' from project 'app')
[15:42:40]: ▸     Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'app' from project 'app')
[15:42:40]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[15:42:40]: Exit status: 65
```

This is the fast lane config that is being used.

```
desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "app.xcodeproj")
    #sync_code_signing
    build_app(workspace: "app.xcworkspace", scheme: "app", export_options: {
      provisioningProfiles: {
        "com.app.app" => "vahStoreProf",
      }
    }, xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates")
    # Changed to update_code_signing_settings from enable_automatic_code_signing since it was deprecated
    update_code_signing_settings(path: "app.xcodeproj")
    upload_to_testflight
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue affecting recent versions of Fastlane running combined with Xcode 14 and/or macOS 13.

You can check open issues:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20810

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20825

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20800

For the time being, the only solution I found in my project is locking a lower version of Xcode in the Fastfile, eg:

```
xcode_select("/Applications/Xcode_13.4.1.app")
```

In case you're running your pipeline on Github, choosing your environment can be relatively easy (easier than downgrading your local machine). Depending on your Github runtime, you may have different versions of Xcode installed. Assuming you're on macOS-latest (macOS 12), [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md#xcode) is a list of available Xcode versions.

Comment: I see. I tried building the app to testflight yesterday and it worked fine. I assume that the issue has been fixed or something happened and its working normally now on Xcode version 14

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
gym(
  ....
  xcargs: "CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="
}
```

To resolve the issue.

Comment: DEVELPMENT_TEAM could be blank?